# How to call function of unmanaged code from vb.net with reference (pointer) out value?

Tags: vb.net, reference, visual-studio-2017, managed-code

I have function **PLInsert2D**
Also it has description in unmanaged code like this:

```
HRESULT PLInsert2D(
[in] IPARTLibProvider* aPLClient;
[in] IBOResponseDisp* aMethodResponse;
[in] Double aX, aY, aAngle;
[out, retval] long* result);
```

I call this function from vb.net vs 2017 win8.1 64bit:

```
<DllImport("C:\Program Files\ASCON\KOMPAS-3D v17\Libs\PARTLib\Clients\plclient_kompas.dll", BestFitMapping:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall, EntryPoint:="LIBRARYENTRY")>
    Public Shared Function PLInsert2D(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> ByVal aPLClient As IPARTLibProvider, <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)> ByVal aMethodResponse As IBOResponse, ByVal aX As Double, ByVal aY As Double, ByVal aAngle As Double) As IntPtr
    End Function
```

and I use it in managed code like this:

```
Dim insert2dpart As IntPtr
        insert2dpart = PLInsert2D(aPLClient, aMethodResponse, aX, aY, aAngle)
```

It returns **&H0000000000000001** What is this? Is this good or bad? What can I do with this value? It should return reference of macroelement, but I think this is not what I expect. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like you have any retval, "result" should be the last parameter passed ByRef but it's missing.

Comment: @NickAbbot `Public Shared Function PLInsert2D( ByVal aPLClient As IPARTLibProvider, ByVal aMethodResponse As IBOResponse, ByVal aX As Double, ByVal aY As Double, ByVal aAngle As Double, ByRef result as integer) As IntPtr`                                                             
 and use it in managed code:      `Dim insert2dpart As IntPtr.                                                                              
  Dim result as integer                                                   result =1
        insert2dpart = PLInsert2D(aPLClient, aMethodResponse, aX, aY, aAngle, result)`?

Comment: Here's a document you may need : [Consuming Unmanaged DLL Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/consuming-unmanaged-dll-functions)

Comment: It's declared to return an HRESULT.  Since the return value is positive, it's a "success" HRESULT.  I think 1 is `S_FALSE`, check the documentation (if available) for what that means, I've worked with code that stupidly uses `S_FALSE` to indicate a failure instead of using an error HRESULT.